# Safari resizing issue with object-fit

Tags: html, css, safari

When resizing elements inside of images that have an object-fit positioned background image, it glitches badly. Here is a [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ba1phujf/) that has an object-fit, absolute positioned background image, and it has a bordered block inside of it. When collapsing the bordered block, only the part of the image that was under and inside the block is correct. Anyone experienced this and know the solution?

```js
function changeSize() {
  const currentHeight = document.getElementById('stretcherdiv').getAttribute("style");
  if (currentHeight === "height:400px;") {
    document.getElementById('stretcherdiv').setAttribute("style", "height:100px;");
  } else {
    document.getElementById('stretcherdiv').setAttribute("style", "height:400px;");
  }
}
```

```css
.outer {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.stretcher {
  height: 20px;
  width: 80px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  border: 1px solid cyan;
  z-index: 100;
  margin: 120px auto;
}

.image {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="changeSize()">
  expand/collapse
</button>

<div class="outer">
  <div class="stretcher" id="stretcherdiv" style="height:400px;"></div>
  <img class="image" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_girl.jpg"> </img>
</div>
```

The problem - Safari after collapsing the bordered block, wrong, bad:

[image]

Any other browser after collapsing the block, the desired behavior, correct, good:

[image]

Comment: @gre_gor The closed question met all the criteria to be legitimate and there was no reason for it to be closed. What else am I supposed to do.

Comment: @gre_gor There's literally a jsfiddle with the problem reproduced in a minimal example

Comment: A JSFiddle is an off-site resource, which is not sufficient for a [mcve]. As the first sentence on the linked page says **in bold**, the code to reproduce the question needs to be **in your question**.

Comment: @TylerH Your provided resource does not state that the use of a freely accessible off-site platform is forbidden in order to provide the code of the executable minimal example. I don't think I'm expected to spam-dump all the code in my question and reduce readability.

Comment: @GeForceRTX4090 You may include links to JSFiddle or other sites, so long as the full code to reproduce your problem is in the code. This is stated in the first sentence of the linked page: "When asking a debugging question, people will be better able to provide help if you provide code *as text* **in your question** that prospective answerers can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem."

Comment: See also: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Looks like a Safari bug, I ran into other glitches when testing your code, like the top part of the image being replicated on the bottom instead of the image expanding. You might need to change your approach.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by applying the absolute position to an image wrapper instead of the image itself.

Seems to be a Safari glitch that can be worked around this way.

```js
function changeSize() {
  const currentHeight = document.getElementById('stretcherdiv').getAttribute("style");
  if (currentHeight === "height:400px;") {
    document.getElementById('stretcherdiv').setAttribute("style", "height:100px;");
  } else {
    document.getElementById('stretcherdiv').setAttribute("style", "height:400px;");
  }
}
```

```css
.outer {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.stretcher {
  height: 20px;
  width: 80px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  border: 1px solid cyan;
  margin: 120px auto;
  z-index:100;
}

.imgwrap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.image {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="changeSize()">
  expand/collapse
</button>

<div class="outer">
  <div class="stretcher" id="stretcherdiv" style="height:400px;"></div>
  <div class="imgwrap">
    <img class="image" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_girl.jpg"> </img>
  </div>

</div>
```